# Re-attaching jQuery detach();

Tags: jquery

I have detached a div and want to re-attach it when clicking on a button.

Here's the code:

```
$('#wrapper').detach();

$("#open_menu").click(function(){
    ATTACH HERE !!!
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about just `append()`'ing it ?

Comment: I have a demo of how to do this at https://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/rf3nrnzo/ - I will write a full answer explaining it and the various methods tomorrow evening when I should have more time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore Multiple Detached Elements in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058896/restore-multiple-detached-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 60):

```
var el = $('#wrapper').detach();

$("#open_menu").click(function(){
    $(this).append(el);
});
```

Answer (score 24):

I needed a solution that would work even if there are other elements after the target element to detach and then reattach. This means that `append` may not be reliable because it would move that element back to the end of its parent. I had to use a placeholder which may not be the most elegant solution, but I haven't found another way..

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper')
    , $placeholder = $('<span style="display: none;" />')
        .insertAfter( $wrapper )
    ;
$wrapper.detach();

$("#open_menu").on('click',function(){
    $wrapper.insertBefore( $placeholder );
    $placeholder.remove();
});
```

To make this more reusable, it might be better to wrap it in a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.detachTemp = function() {
        this.data('dt_placeholder',$('<span style="display: none;" />')
            .insertAfter( this ));
        return this.detach();
    }

    $.fn.reattach = function() {
        if(this.data('dt_placeholder')){
            this.insertBefore( this.data('dt_placeholder') );
            this.data('dt_placeholder').remove();
            this.removeData('dt_placeholder');
        }
        else if(window.console && console.error)
        console.error("Unable to reattach this element because its placeholder is not available.");
        return this;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper').detachTemp();
$("#open_menu").on('click',function(){
    $wrapper.reattach();
});
```

Comment: Performing an append operation in `console.error(..)` to preserve consistent line widths is unnecessary!

Answer (score 6):

if you want your item to attach at the beginning of the element you could use .prepend()

otherwise you could attach it using append().

in your case it would be:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper').detach();

$("#open_menu").click(function(){
    //ATTACH HERE !!!
    $(this).prepend($wrapper); // or $(this).append($wrapper);
});
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is largely a matter of recording the index of the element that will be detached, before detaching it, then using that index for determining where to re-attach the element.  Consider the following "repl" https://repl.it/@dexygen/re-attach and the code below.  The `setTimeout` is merely so you can see the element in the page before it gets detached, and a couple of elements have been renamed.  I wonder if `siblings` can be used instead of `parent().children()` but am concerned what happens in the event the detached sibling is the *only* element among siblings, and we need a reference to `parent` anyway, for *prepending* if `index === 0`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var bar = $('#bar');
    var parent = bar.parent();
    var index = parent.children().index(bar);

    bar.detach();

    $("#re-attach").one('click', function() {
        if (index === 0) {
            parent.prepend(bar);  
        }
        else {
            parent.children().eq(index-1).after(bar);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
 var detached = $('#element_to_detach').detach();
 // Here We store the detach element to the new variable named detached
 $('.element_after_which_you_need_to_attach').after(detached);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper').detach();

$("#open_menu").click(function(){
    $(this).append($wrapper[0])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `prepend()` the detached element after assigning it to a variable, ie.

```
var det_elem = $('#wrapper').detach();
$("#open_menu").click(function(){
    $(this).prepend(det_elem);
});
```

**prepend()** will attach at the beginning of the element.

Answer (score -10):

jQuery does not offer an attach method. Consider that detach is the equivalent of permanently deleting an item from the Dom. If you believe that you might want to remove and later bring back an element, consider the following options:

1. Use the toggle method. To hide and unhide elements from the page.
2. If you must absolutely remove the item from the Dom, consider using the jQuery clone method, to first make a copy of the specified element, which you can then later reintroduce the element copy back to the Dom.

The above are not the only two ways to accomplish this, however, they are simply and would likely not require much code changes on your end.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. If you read the docs (https://api.jquery.com/detach/) these state the following- "The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. *This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time*.". Emphasis my own. Detach is useful to avoid layout thrashing when appending many children to an element for example.

Comment: Just added a downvote to prevent others from getting misinformation--Cheers for commenting and making me think anyway. :)