# How to remove and recreate element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements and I want to remove this element on responsive but I want to recreate again on desktop

I mean I want to remove this element in `if` and I want to create again in `else`

my project is something like that

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width <=768){
       $('.element').remove();
   }else{
    //create again 
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
<p>something here..</p>
</div>
```

footnote: please I don't want to hide it because it div is showing when I scroll then if I hide it after scroll on mobile then it will be shown again..

Comment: why not using css media queries

Comment: footnote: please I don't want to hide it because it div is showing when I scroll then if I hide it after scroll on mobile then it will be shown again..

Comment: what you exactly mean by this `div is showing when I scroll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try hide and show, because if you remove it you will need some hidden element to clone it or add it back. I would suggest you using hide/show

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width <=768){
       $('.element').hide();
   }else{
       $('.element').show();
  }
}).resize();
```

or using `css media query`

```
@media(screen and max-width: 768px) {
.element {
    display: none;
    }

}
```

or if you want to use remove then make a global variable and assing `.element` to it.

```
var obj = $(".element");
$(window).resize(function(){
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width <=768){
       $('.element').remove();
   }else{
       $('body').append(obj);
  }
}).resize();
```

Comment: footnote: please I don't want to hide it because it div is showing when I scroll then if I hide it after scroll on mobile then it will be shown again..

Comment: @ani_css you've put that comment everywhere in this question, yet it makes no sense whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to remove the element, don't actually use `remove()` when you want to reinsert it again. Use `detach()` (https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

The following is an example from [Re-attaching jQuery detach();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534601/re-attaching-jquery-detach)

```
var el = $('.element');
if(width <=768){
    el.detach();
}else{
    $(body).append(el);
}
```

Detaching ensures that the element **keeps jQuery data associated** with it for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to delete and restore it for a responsive-like design? You could be using CSS Media-Queries instead, which is much more resource-friendly and overall the better approach:

```
@media(screen and max-width: 768px) {
    .element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you would have to use JS, you should use `.hide()` and `.show()`, which essentially does the same thing except via JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var width = $(window).width();

   if(width <= 768) {
       $('.element').hide();
   } 
   else {
       $('.element').show();
  }
}).resize();
```

If I'm not getting your point and you actually *have to* do it the JS way via deleting and restoring, please let me know in a comment and I will try to help.

Comment: footnote: please I don't want to hide it because it div is showing when I scroll then if I hide it after scroll on mobile then it will be shown again..

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to imply with that, sorry. Using a media query would completely hide the element from any view on any device compatible with media queries once the resolution reaches a maximum with of and including 768 pixels.

Comment: sorry about my bad english..so this element is hidden element on desktop  up to scroll down that's wht if I hide on mobile after scroll it will be shown again

Comment: That doesn't happen when you are using the media query I provided, as scrolling, or any event at all, doesn't change that media query unless you override the CSS rule `display` with an `!important` appendix.

Comment: but it's happening I tried and I don't use any important to show or hide

Comment: Please edit in your code-samples you added based on this question. If further discussion is required, please transfer to chat, as comments are not allowed to be used for extended discussion.