# WooCommerce: Add content after product title and meta in cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to display some custom content after every item in the cart.

In the template `cart.php` I found the following hook:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

The problem is, that my custom content will show after the product name but before every meta content like variation data. But after this hook there is no other hook to work with and the text table cell starts.

Is there any way to add content at the very end of the `product-name` table cell without touching the template file?

Comment: You could use jQuery.

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534601/re-attaching-jquery-detach