# Re-attach an detached div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have detached a div and want to re-attach it when a certain requirement has been met.

Here's the code so far:

```
let armor,
    armorcontainer = $(".hud-status"),
    armorhud = $(".hud-armor");

let stress,
    stresscontainer = $(".hud-status"),
    stresshud = $(".hud-stress");

if (data.armor == 0 || data.armor < 1) {
    armor = armorhud.detach();
} else {
    armorcontainer.append(armor);
}

if (data.stress == 0 || data.stress < 1) {
    stress = stresshud.detach();
} else {
    stresscontainer.append(stress);
}
```

With this code, not only doesn't it go away, but all the other hud divs are visible too, except the Armor hud, that one is indeed gone.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Put `$('.hud-armor')` into a variable before you detach, and then you may be able to reattach it?

Comment: @isherwood I'm not confident in my suggestion to make it an answer. I've never used this method

Comment: @IMSoP I tried that one out, but when I did that all my hud divs are still showing. even if i put in all requirement the append when requirement met and detach when requirement not met.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Your suggestion is I think the same as this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534601/re-attaching-jquery-detach which didn't work as I told above.

Comment: You haven't actually shown the reattachment part, nor explained why it didn't work

Comment: Please may you remove the last two comments and edit the question?

Comment: The udpated example doesn't make sense since, when the if is true, the prepend won't run.

Comment: Even if i try to put them outside the if statement, it still gives the same result. It gives me an error that i noticed now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

Comment: Yeah, because you're creating the variable inside the true if block, but then reattaching in the else block. That doesn't make sense

Comment: i even put the var outside the if/else, but then i got this issue. Changed the code in start post.

Comment: Here's a working example https://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/QWqZYmw?editors=1011

Comment: I tried that @evolutionxbox, it kind of works but then it ruins this up: https://i.imgur.com/ixtR1ZT.png As you see it sets the stress hud on the wrong location. Normally it should be like this: https://i.imgur.com/nHwVLQM.png. But normally how i started with onyl detach(), it went good, for example temvoing the armor with detach, the stress will take it's place, now it doesnt with the code you gave me. (I edited the post again for the latest.)

Comment: Double-check the order of the HTML. It might be that you need a different method than `prepend` or `append`?