# Why remove() or detach() instead of hide()?

Tags: jquery

Why do we have to `remove()` or `detach()` elements from Document Object Model when we can just `hide()` in j Query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't **have to** remove or detach. But you **can**. What I mean is that it depends on the situation.

When to use `hide`:

hiding is simply applying an inline style of `display: none`. Hiding is fast and useful if you want to temporarily hide something and then show it.

When to use `remove`:

when you call `remove()` you physically remove the element(s) from the DOM. The elements, along with all their data and event listeners. This is useful if you are done with the element and you won't be needing it again. Hiding it would just leave garbage in your DOM.

When to use `detach`:

detaching is very similar to removing but when you detach an element you keep its data and event listeners. This is useful if you want to move and element from one place in the DOM to another.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `detach()` or `remove()`, to block screen readers and search engines, as well as users from seeing them, because, it removes elements from the DOM.

You should use `hide()` when you want to hide something from the end user,but not from screen readers,  because they are hidden from using `css`.