# Using jQuery remove and detach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an almost full operational app but I have a problem I cannot solve. I want to remove an element including all text and child nodes, using the jQuery `remove()` method. If I use the `detach()` method it works, but the data is kept, and that is not a solution for me.

This is the html code:

```
<div id="scroll-add">
    ...
    <li class="layer_add">
        <?PHP
        for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
            ?>
            <ul>
                <li class       = "todo unchecked" 
                    data-breed  = "<? echo $breed[$i]; ?>" 
                <? echo $breed[$i]; ?></li> 
            </ul>
            <?PHP
        }
        ?>                              
    </li>
</div>
```

and the query:

```
$(".checkbox input").change(function () {
    $(this).parents("span").toggleClass("checked");
    var catFileName = $(this).attr("data-catFileName");
    var dogFileName = $(this).attr("data-dogFileName");

    if($(this).parents("span").hasClass("checked")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../iPhone/inc/breed.php",
            data: {'fileName': dogFileName},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){

            $("#scroll-add").children("li.layer_add").detach();
                    $("#scroll-add").append('<li class="layer_add">');
                    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        $("li.layer_add").append('<ul><li class="todo unchecked" data-breed="' + data[i] + '"></li></ul>');
                    }
                    $("#scroll-add").append('</li>');
                }
            },
            ...
```

The question is that when I use:

```
$("#scroll-add").children("li.layer_add").detach()
```

the elements are removed.

But when I use:

```
$("#scroll-add").children("li.layer_add").remove()
```

nothing happens.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery

Comment: Thanks @malkam. I have seen that before and that's pretty informative. But I cannot put remove() to work... Its getting me mad!

Comment: Tried `.detach()` with pieces at original post , appear to work ok at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/d9pAs/ ?

Comment: Thanks @guest271314. So it proves this piece of code works. It seems that I will have to look deeper in other parts of my code, since .remove() still doesn't work in it (but .detach() works)...