# Re-appending input element makes its events not fire

Tags: jquery

I've got an input and an event handler attached to it

```
var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
input.on('keypress', function (e) {
    alert('You pressed ' + e.which);
});
```

I append it to a div and all works fine.

```
$('div').append(input);
```

But then when I remove it and then re-append it,

```
$('div').html('removed')
$('div').append(input);
```

my event handler attached to the input doesn't work! Why and how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/laggingreflex/35p2hg2h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just remove your element by blanking the `html`. Use [.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and the events will be preserved:

http://jsfiddle.net/35p2hg2h/1/

```
input.detach();     // preserves the event handlers
$('div').html('Input removed. wait for it...')
setTimeout(function () {
    $('div').html('Input appended again, but now events dont fire :?') // actually, now
                                                                       // they will
    $('div').append(input);
}, 1000);
```

See also:

[Differences between detach(), hide() and remove() - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery)