# Loop works just 16 times instead of 36

Tags: javascript

Hello I am now at black out mode while trying to create this loop 
The code is like this :

```
function finished() {
    var summaryDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    summaryDiv.setAttribute("id","summary");
    document.getElementById("main_content").appendChild(summaryDiv);

    var summaryLabel = document.createElement("P");
    summaryLabel.setAttribute("id","score");
    document.getElementById("summary").appendChild(summaryLabel);

    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var value = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked && radios[i].value == "true") {
            value += 1;
            console.log(value);
        } else {
            console.log(value);  
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("qcontainer")[i].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = value;
    } 

}
```

//The value of radios.length is 36, and it seems like it takes the value only of first 16 radio buttons, it doesnt matter if another 8 radio buttons have value TRUE it always returns only TRUEs from the first 16 radio Buttons, I know it might be a little bit confusing but I don't know what is wrong with this loop.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: include the HTML

Comment: It looks ok at first glance.  You should create a fiddle or something so people can see the problem happening.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is live. When you remove `input` elements from DOM, `radios.length` will decrease.

Comment: OMG Wazner Buddy! You saved me like really saved me! Thank you!

Comment: @Wazner May be write it as an answer and complete this experience.

Comment: @Wazner , @Przemo: This code does not remove the input element from the page, it just sets `style=display:none` which should not change the size of HTMLCollection created by `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qmk5hLs/4) shows the loop you have posted works correctly and iterates over all radio elements. `style.display="none"` does not affect the loop. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a live `HtmlCollection`. This means that when you remove an element from DOM, either through `removeChild` or by setting `innerHTML` of a parent the collection is updated.

A possible way to loop over a live `HtmlCollection` like this is to perform a while on the `.length` of the collection.

```
while (radios.length) {
    // Use radios[0]
    // Remove radios[0] from DOM
}
```

Comment: This is correct. But the code in the question does NOT remove elements from the DOM. `style=display:none` does not remove the element. [The answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery) describes the difference (in the context of jquery).

Comment: But `document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = value;` may remove elements from DOM.

Comment: Maybe, although `score` is a `<P>` element, not a radio input. The question needs to be updated with HTML.

Comment: Yeah, the question is vague, that's why I initially posted it as a comment.