# How to remove a div without using its ID

Tags: javascript, html, parent, removechild

Divs are created every update and their positions are randomized inside "levelWrapper". All these divs share a class named *tree*. Whenever I click a div that has *tree* as a class, the code runs through all existing *tree* classed divs and compares their positions in relation to the mouse click coordinates. If their position is within click range (which is 100px) then **I want to remove said divs**.

**Here's what I have that already does what I want** *BUT* bugs after the first run through the code. I *think* I know why it bugs, read below.

```js
var i = 0,
  a = 0;

function newTree() {
  var newTree = document.createElement('div');
  newTree.id = 'tree' + i;
  newTree.className = 'tree';
  document.getElementById("levelWrapper").appendChild(newTree);
}

function positionTree() {
  var levelWidth = document.getElementById("levelWrapper").offsetWidth;
  var levelHeight = document.getElementById("levelWrapper").offsetHeight;

  var treeX = Math.round(Math.random() * levelWidth);
  var treeY = Math.round(Math.random() * levelHeight);

  document.getElementById("tree" + i).style.left = treeX + "px";
  document.getElementById("tree" + i).style.top = treeY + "px";
}

function createTree() {
  a += 1;
  if (a == 20) {
    newTree(); // new div
    positionTree(); // position div
    a = 0; // reset counter for new div
    i++; // new ID for new div
  }
}

function getMouseCoordinates(e) {
  var offset = $('#levelWrapper').offset();
  mouseX = Math.round(e.clientX - offset.left);
  mouseY = Math.round(e.clientY - offset.top);
}

var clickRange = 100;

function update() {
  createTree();

  $('div.tree').click(function(e) {
    getMouseCoordinates(e);
    var numItems = $('.tree').length;

    for (g = 0; g < numItems; g++) {
      var p = $("#tree" + g).position();

      if ((p.left > (mouseX - clickRange)) &
        (p.left < (mouseX + clickRange)) &
        (p.top > (mouseY - clickRange)) &
        (p.top < (mouseY + clickRange))) {

        p = document.getElementById("tree" + g);
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
      }
    }
  });
}

function mainLoop() {
  update();
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
#levelWrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.tree {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="levelWrapper"></div>
```

It bugs because on the second run, this line `var p = $("#tree" + g).position();` selects a div that has been deleted so it returns a null.

New divs are still created, but the click/remove function stops working.

I could probably do something along the lines of "if (null) ..." BUT the div IDs keep increasing, easily getting up to 200+ divs that the for loop has to go through and that is visibly slow.

So instead of removing divs through their IDs, I thought of having some array referencing them and whenever I delete one div, the array "cascades" down, reducing the ammount of checking I have to do,  and avoiding the null return whenever it tries to find the offset left and top of a removed div.

Comment: Why are you insisting on mixing DOM and jQuery? It is not the way. Show the HTML and which div(s) to remove in a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried `$('.tree').remove()`?

Comment: @MattGregory I did, it removes _all_ divs inside .tree, when i want to remove specified ones only

Comment: You say you want to remove only specified ones, but from the rest of your question it looks like you're trying to remove _all_ divs with class 'tree'. So what is different about the ones you want to remove? They have class 'tree' and something else, so what is that something else?

Comment: @mplungjan Done. The div I want to remove is the one specified by the index

Comment: `var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("tree");` returns a DOM collection. What did you THINK it returned? You need to click `<>`, get some actual HTML together, write CLEARLY which div(s) you want to remove when

Comment: I think you're tilted over nothing. I won't "get some actual HTML together" because that's all the HTML I need for what I am doing. All the rest is to be created by JS, divs created by JS and removed by JS. I thought with `var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("tree");` I would have an array with all elements by class name "tree", what the heck else do I get? LOL "Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. ". And so, I thought I could remove the elements through the array. I'm obviously not proficient or literate enought in coding but

Comment: I don't see what's so farfetched in what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. test the existence:

---

```
   for (g = 0; g < numItems; g++) {
      var $div = $("#tree" + g);
      if ($div.length==0) continue;
      var p = $div.position();

      if ((p.left > (mouseX - clickRange)) &
        (p.left < (mouseX + clickRange)) &
        (p.top > (mouseY - clickRange)) &
        (p.top < (mouseY + clickRange))) {

        $div.remove();
      }
    }
```

2. Delegate - You add a click handler every time you loop

---

```
 $('#levelWrapper').on('click','div.tree',function(e) {
  getMouseCoordinates(e);
  $('.tree').each(function() {
    var p = $(this).position();
```

```js
var i = 0,
  a = 0;

function newTree() {
  i = $('#levelWrapper').children().length;
  var $newTree = $('<div/>', {
    'id': 'tree' + i,
    'class': 'tree'
  }); // .text(i); 
  $('#levelWrapper').append($newTree);
}

function positionTree() {
  var levelWidth = document.getElementById("levelWrapper").offsetWidth;
  var levelHeight = document.getElementById("levelWrapper").offsetHeight;

  var treeX = Math.round(Math.random() * levelWidth);
  var treeY = Math.round(Math.random() * levelHeight);

  document.getElementById("tree" + i).style.left = treeX + "px";
  document.getElementById("tree" + i).style.top = treeY + "px";
}

function createTree() {
  a += 1;
  if (a == 20) {
    newTree(); // new div
    positionTree(); // position div
    a = 0; // reset counter for new div
    i++; // new ID for new div
  }
}

function getMouseCoordinates(e) {
  var offset = $('#levelWrapper').offset();
  mouseX = Math.round(e.clientX - offset.left);
  mouseY = Math.round(e.clientY - offset.top);
}

var clickRange = 100;


function mainLoop() {
  createTree();
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}


$(function() {
  $('#levelWrapper').on('click','div.tree',function(e) {
    getMouseCoordinates(e);
    $('.tree').each(function() {
      var p = $(this).position();

      if ((p.left > (mouseX - clickRange)) &
        (p.left < (mouseX + clickRange)) &
        (p.top > (mouseY - clickRange)) &
        (p.top < (mouseY + clickRange))) {

        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
});
```

```css
#levelWrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.tree {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="levelWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Why is there a $ before the variable newTree? What does `$(this).remove();` actually removes? You got most of it right in terms of what I wanted, thank you for understanding, but I also want to remove all other divs within the area of click -- not just the clicked one. I've updated my question and code, you should be able to copy and paste it (if not let me know :l) I've cut a lot of what I actually had, so I hope it's closer to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Using $var is to show it is a jQuery object. Nothing special. $(this) is the clicked object - the div in the container clicked

Comment: See my updated answer. I moved the clicking to a delegated event handler and added an onload handler - I also use more jQuery where useful

Comment: what does `$div.lenght` return? What do you mean by delegate? I already had a click function every update, I see yours is different though

Comment: The number of divs with class tree+g - which is zero if it was not found

Comment: tree+g is the id, not class. So, returns 0 if none found, 1 if found? And if so, shouldn't it be the opposite? `if ($div.lenght == 1) continue`

Comment: Continue skips the rest of the code in the loop so no.. the length is how to test in jQuery if an object exists

Comment: 1. and 2. are two different ways of doing it?

Comment: No. The code in the old answer is now part of the new answer

Comment: I deleted the old answer now

Comment: I'm not using the for loop in 1. at all and everything is working

Answer (score 1):

lets say you want to remove all elements with class name "child" from your tree:

`$(".tree > .child").remove();`

or to remove your tree children by index use:

```
var children = $(".tree").children();
[1,2,5].forEach(function(i) { children[i].remove(); });
```

Here you are setting the array indexes you want to remove. Be aware that this is zero based! So first element is 0.
Here i am removing elements with index 1, 2 and 5. Type whatever indexes you like!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$('.tree').remove();` is what you are looking for.

edit:
Based on the comments to your question, maybe you are trying to remove the children of class="tree"?

If so that would be:

```
$('.tree').children().remove();
```

and if you wanted to remove only the additional instances of class="tree" and not the first one, then you could do:

```
$('.tree').slice(1).children().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery documentation on [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> We can also include a selector as an optional parameter. For example, we could rewrite the previous DOM removal code as follows:
>
> ```
> $( "div" ).remove( ".hello" );
> ```

I think you want to remove only the first element with class of `.tree`, so you could use `:first-child` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tree').remove(':first-child');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='tree'>Tree 1</div>
    <div class='tree'>Tree 2</div>
    <div>Etc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    var temp = $('.tree');
     $(temp[0]).detach();
```

Or

```
    var temp = $('.tree');
     $(temp[0]).remove();
```

The diference between detach and remove you can see at [Differences between detach(), hide() and remove() - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top)