# Why do I need to detach elements before I can swap them in a second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it's better to explain my question with an example:

1. Run the code snippet.

   1. First click swap on the code snippet (three buttons will be added)
   2. then click remove
   3. then click swap again.
   4. You'll notice that the buttons don't come back.
2. Now refresh the page.

   1. Click swap  (three buttons will be added)
   2. then click detach
   3. then click swap again.
   4. You'll notice that the buttons DO come back.

My question is why is this happening? In my mind, I have the buttons stored in a variable either way, so why is it necessary to detach them before I swap them back in again?

```js
const swappable = $(".swap").each(function(index) {
            $(this).data("swap-index", index).after(`<span class="swap-placeholder" data-act-index="${index}"></span>`).detach();
        });

$("#swap-button").on("click", () => {
  swappable.each(function() {
        console.log('this', this)
        const index = $(this).data("swap-index");
        console.log('index', index);
        $(`.swap-placeholder[data-act-index="${index}"]`).after(this);
    });
});

$("#remove-button").on("click", () => {
  $(".swap").remove();
});
$("#detach-button").on("click", () => {
  $(".swap").detach();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="swap-button">Swap</button>
<button type="button" id="remove-button">Remove</button>
<button type="button" id="detach-button">Detach</button>

<button type="button" class="swap">swap1</button>

<button type="button" class="swap">swap2</button>

<button type="button" class="swap">swap3</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery

Comment: @epascarello thanks but I already knew all that information